# XNA project - who is in charge of drawing?

Tags: xna

I am just playing around with XNA, and I have several different models I need to draw in each frame.
at the moment, the Game object holds references to all my models, and draws them one after the other. Each with his own different way of drawing - one has two separate textures, the other might be mirrored to the other side, etc.

I was wondering if it is acceptable to just add a

`public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)`

method to all my models (from the BaseModel, of course), and have each class be in charge of drawing itself, or maybe I should stick to letting the classes set their data according to events (KeyboardState) on the Update method, and keep all graphic logic in the Game class.

Is there a preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, I have a base class that contains a BaseModel, texture data, rotation and scale data, etc. For each type of actor in the game, I create a derived class. The base class provides a Draw method that, by default, draws the model with the texture, rotation, and scale data given in the class. Derived classes can override it to draw the actor however they like.

Then, I have a DrawableGameComponent that acts as my scene graph. It contains a list of all active actor objects. In the component's Draw and Update methods, I iterate through the list of actors and call their Draw and Update methods.

Answer (score 3):

That's one way of approaching it ... for the sake of completeness in this post, I'll highlight the other approach.  Basically, the opposing view states that no one entity should need (or have) custom knowledge of how to render itself. An entity is merely a collection of state ... and the renderer can simply look at that state, and draw it in the correct way.

An example ... say you have a number of ships.  Some go fast, some shoot rockets, some have a sattelite orbiting around it that also shoots.  Your "Entity" class can have the following properties

- Model VisualRepresentation
- Matrix Position
- Entity[] AttachedEntities

Your renderer can then iterate over your generic "`List<Entity>`", and

1. Draw the visual representation (ie. Model) of the entity using the position
2. Loop over the AttachedEntities and draw them (recursively).

It's obviously a simplified example ... but this way the drawing logic is completely contained in the rendering code, and only needs to concern itself with as little amount of information as possible.  While the ship class can focus on the game logic itself (ie. how fast do I fly, what weapon am I using, how much energy do I have in my shields, etc.).

As far as which one is preferred, really the answer lies within your project's requirements, and what you feel comfortable with.  Don't try to make a game engine before making a game ... just do whatever it takes to make your game, and then *maybe* you can extract the components that worked *after* you ship the game :-P

Comment: Thanks for the other view on things